# Where is this taken from?

Tags: discussion

I've been wondering for a long time what the picture on the top right corner of Sci-Fi SE site is.

[image]

So is this taken from a famous movie, book or is it something original made for the site itself?

Comment: I've moved this to meta and closed it as a dupe but in short the theming (original theming, top banner is still the same) was created by [jin](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/44/jin), a SE employee at the time.